# Why should one chose the HttpGet/HttpPost method's over kSoap?

Tags: android

I am due to make an android application which sends and recieves data from a .Net web service . I have implemented the HttpGet method in the android and was able to get data in the JSON format .

I will now be implementing the HttpPost method where in i will be sending JSON data to the server.

I was also going through ksoap libary which i think does the soap parsing in the android phone .

Could anyone please tell me why i should/shouldnt be using ksoap and HttpGet and HttpPost methods ?????

As in which amongst this is a better solution KSOAP or (HttpGet/HttpPost)  ???
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kSOAP is a library that deals with the various aspects of the SOA-Protocol. Internally it will use http get and post to communicate with a server.

If you want/need full control over what is sent, direct http may be better. Otherwise I think kSOAP may be better / higher level.